# Throw unformatted 401 in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I've got the following piece of code:

```
            if (!checkAuthCode(LoginAuthenticatieCode))
            {
                throw new HttpException(401, "Auth Failed");
            }
```

This code checks if the user is authenticated, and if not throws a 401 exception. The only problem being, somewhere along the way this 401 gets packaged into a nice-looking 500 error, saying

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Auth Failed",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.Web.HttpException",
>   "StackTrace": "   bij
>   WebApplication1.Controllers.loginController.checkAuthCodeOrThrow(String
>   LoginAuthenticatieCode) in blablabla

Is there a way to prevent ASP.NET (or MVC, I don't know which of the two is responsible) from wrapping my error in this "nice" human-readable form?

Comment: @Neel Yup, my bad... Corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you sure this is MVC and not a WebAPI controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a WebAPI controller, and you're throwing an MVC exception. This difference will be unified with MVC 6 / vNext.

For now, MVC and WebAPI use different assemblies and namespaces. The `System.Web.HttpException` you throw is not recognized as an HTTP exception by WebAPI, so it thinks your application has thrown a random exception and formats that as a JSON-formatted 500 Internal Server Error.

So for WebAPI, throw a `new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`. This will generate an HTTP 401.

Comment: I though that the proper way is to return an error result, like [HttpUnauthorizedResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult(v=vs.118).aspx) ? Assuming the OP *is* using MVC instead of Web API

Comment: I am indeed throwing this from a WebAPI controller. I'm fairly new to the whole MVC and ASP.NET and everything, so I guess I forgot to include some important information there. Thank you for your answer, it works now as I want it to.

Comment: @Panagiotis OP is using WebAPI. :P I think using a class per HTTP response code is a bit silly, and generally use [`HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) in MVC. Though you can't do that if you have model-typed action methods instead of `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET MVC use `HttpException(401, "Some message...")`.

For ASP.NET WebAPI use `HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`.